# DLL is missing from your computer error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that works great.

I created a **new and independent** `.dll` project that contains the origin project with some exported functions (copied the origin `.h` and `.cpp` files to the new project). I copied from the origin project all the lib dependencies and paths to those libs and additional include files. its the same setup.

The new program compiles but the problem is that when I try to run the code, I get that error msg:

`The program can't start because xxx.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

that `xxx.lib` is on the `Additional dependencies` list and its not the first one:

`Additional Dependencies:   aaa.lib; bbb.lib; ccc.lib; xxx.lib, zzz.lib`

I guess that VS found the first three `.lib` otherwise I would get some error message.. so why can't it find `xxx.lib`? all the `.lib` files in the same folder..

thanks.

Comment: If you're running the executable via VS, then you need to place the DLL at the correct path relatively to your project (or change this path in your project settings, according to where you want to place the DLL). If you run the executable directly (i.e., not via VS), then you can simply place the DLL on the same path alongside the executable.

Comment: Hi, so why doesn't it complains about the first three libs?

Comment: It says "xxx.dll is missing from your computer", doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be misreading the error message. It says:

> The program can't start because xxx.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Note that it says xxx.**dll** is missing, not xxx.**lib**!

On Windows, a LIB file is often used as an aid to the linker when using a DLL. The LIB contains import stubs for functions provided by the DLL. You need the LIB file when you build the binary; you don't need the LIB file on the machine to run the resulting binary. However, you *do* need the DLL!

The reason that this might be confusing is that, if you are going to statically link an object file, you only need the LIB. It contains all of the code, and there is no DLL required. But this is not the strategy you are using. The linker is using the xxx.lib file to arrange for the EXE to be dynamically linked to xxx.dll. Thus, the EXE requires the DLL to be present in order for it to run.

Copy xxx.dll into the same folder as your EXE, and then launch the application again. This has nothing to do with your compiler/linker/build settings.

Comment: Hi, instead of copying the lib files (its quite messy..) I tried to put the path of the dll file in `working directory` and the lib path to `Enviroment` and I still get that error.. some sites says that the `Enviroment` should point to `dll` and some of them to `lib`. Im bit confused, how hould I configure that? in both cases I still get this error.. :\